# Retrieve carousel caption from current index bootstrap 4 and display in another div

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display the carousel text from the bootstrap 4 carousel in another div.

So far I can get the current index and I can also get the text separately, but I cannot work out how to join the two together.

My code is below, can anyone help join the dots.

```
$('#carousel-1').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e){
  e.from          // The index of the current item. 
    alert(e.from);
});

$(".carousel-text").append($(".carousel-caption").html());
```

-------------UPDATE----------------------------

I have it working, but now have a delay in displaying carousel-caption

So slide 2 will show slide 1 caption

I have tried adding setTimout to match that of slider interval, but no luck

New code

```
$('#carousel-1').on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e){
var carouselText = $('.active').find('.carousel-caption').html();
    $(".carousel-text").append(carouselText).html("");
     $(".carousel-text").append(carouselText).html();
 });
```

Comment: The "current" slide in a BS carousel has the class of "active" so you should be able to target that and get the text element you want from the p element or whatever yuo have in that slide.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, if anyone else comes across this here is my working code

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
});

$('.carousel-text').html($('.active > .carousel-caption').html());
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $('.carousel-text').html($('.active > .carousel-caption').html());
    });
```